# What's in Android cursor index -1?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I have just started Android.

So I'm using SQLite for an apps, and comes to something like

```
Cursor c = new Cursor()
c = db.rawquery(randomQueryString, null)

if (c!=null) 
    c.moveToFirst();
```

So, I have read somewhere that cursor default position is -1, and it is, according to the code above, not null, then what kind of data could possibly be in this position?

Comment: apparently your cursor is simply empty. there is no data matching your query.

Comment: That I know, but my question is about the characteristic of this -1 position, and why somebody have to put the `c!=null` there.

Comment: the cursor comes from http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%29 , which can in fact be null if something happens in the driver. -1 is before first. (can be tested with cursor.isBeforeFirst())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the position "before first", being in this position make it more simple and clear to write a code to iterate thorough data in this cursor, you need just start looping from first as you would do in any other position.

Example:

```
if (cursor == null) {
    //handle
}
while (cusor.moveToNext()) {
    //do somehitng
}
```

Comment: Does this means that I can just omit the `(if c != null)` part?

Comment: No, it should be null if no result was found, you just don't need the moveToFirst() before iterating.